# scrapy installation error

Tags: gcc, error-handling, scrapy, easy-install

i'm having trouble running easy_install scrapy and got the following error:

```
**cc1.exe: error: unrecognized command line option '-mno -cygwin'
error: setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1**
```

i'm running python 2.7 on windows 32 bit. i installed mingw, libxslt, liblxml2. what's going on there? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to remove all instances of -mno-cygwin from C:\Python27\Lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py, re-run easy_install.

I had this same problem and I found the answer here:

http://www.techques.com/question/1-6034390/Compiling-with-cython-and-mingw-produces-gcc:-error:-unrecognized-command-line-option-'-mno-cygwin'

I had GCC version 4.6.2 installed which did not support the -mno-cygwin option.