# Having trouble in installing Scrapy in Windows

Tags: python, scrapy

I was install Scrapy using in Windows (64 bit).

And I got stuck when its shows error in finding vcvarsall.bat:

```
Installed c:\python27\lib\site-packages\w3lib-1.10.0-py2.7.egg
Searching for cryptography>=0.2.1
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cryptography/
Best match: cryptography 0.5.4
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cryptography/cryptography-
0.5.4.tar.gz#md5=4fd1f10e9f99009a44667fabe7980aec
Processing cryptography-0.5.4.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\acer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0yx5l\cryptography-0.5.4\
setup.cfg
Running cryptography-0.5.4\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\acer\appdat
a\local\temp\easy_install-v0yx5l\cryptography-0.5.4\egg-dist-tmp-tfxf5w
Searching for cffi>=0.8
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/cffi/
Best match: cffi 0.8.6
Downloading https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/c/cffi/cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz#md5
=474b5a68299a6f05009171de1dc91be6
Processing cffi-0.8.6.tar.gz
Writing c:\users\acer\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-v0yx5l\cryptography-0.5.4\
temp\easy_install-x3fgjg\cffi-0.8.6\setup.cfg
Running cffi-0.8.6\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir c:\users\acer\appdata\local\
temp\easy_install-v0yx5l\cryptography-0.5.4\temp\easy_install-x3fgjg\cffi-0.8.6\
egg-dist-tmp-dtqwwf
error: Setup script exited with error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

Comment: Do you have Visual Studio installed?

Comment: @wRAR I don't find that solving this issue by installing Visual Studio i.e around 900mb.. for small script...

Comment: You need libraries which need other libraries which need to be compiled. So you need a compiler.

Comment: I just solved my issue by following this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2817869/error-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat

Answer (score 1):

Another way to get around the missing vcvarsall.bat is to install the Microsoft Visual C++ compiler for Python 2.7 http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266

when you get that error you might want to just find a Windows installer for it, it will include the missing file. 
http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/files/

here's an explanation of the error. 
http://slacy.com/blog/2010/09/python-unable-to-find-vcvarsall-bat/

Previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215220/installing-scrapy-under-windows7?rq=1)

Comment: I don't find that solving this issue by installing Visual Studio i.e around 900mb.. for small script...

Comment: I don't recall telling you to install VS. I stated you need to install the module from someone who has compiled and created an installer for Windows. The second link documents why the error, they resolve it by installing VS.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
easy_install scrapy
```

This works for me without any error.