# Scrapy installation on cygwin

Tags: cygwin, installation, scrapy

I'm trying to get Scrapy running on cygwin 2.7 using the command `easy_install Scrapy` however I'm a warning followed by a gcc error:

```
warning: no files found matching '*.txt' under directory 'src/lxml/tests'
unable to execute gcc: No such file or directory
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1`
```

There are some related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10922967/scrapy-installation-error) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14024910/scrapy-installation-problems), but both seem to address issues different my current problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find any `gcc` package with my version of Cygwin :

```
$ apt-cyg install gcc
Installing gcc
Unable to locate package gcc
```

But installing the `gcc-g++` package did the trick:

```
$ apt-cyg install gcc-g++
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install gcc package, using the cygwin setup.exe or apt-cyg

```
apt-cyg install gcc
# Create a symlink to be able to run gcc
ln -s /usr/bin//i686-pc-cygwin-gcc-3.exe /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: I wiped the computer this was on and installed ubuntu, so I can't confirm that this works, but it seems reasonable